# How to graph families of site index curves?

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I'm a beginner in R and I don't know what code to use. I need to graph the following data in a graph with all curves (IS 12.7, IS 15.0, IS 16.9 IS, 20.7)

```
s/e (IS 12,7)(IS 15,0)(IS 16,9)(IS 20,7)
1   0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1
2   1,2 1,4 1,5 1,9
3   2,8 3,3 3,7 4,6
4   4,4 5,2 5,8 7,1
5   5,7 6,7 7,6 9,3
6   6,8 8,1 9,1 11,1
7   7,7 9,1 10,3    12,6
8   8,5 10,1    11,3    13,9
9   9,2 10,8    12,2    15
10  9,7 11,5    12,9    15,9
11  10,2    12,1    13,6    16,7
12  10,6    12,6    14,1    17,4
13  11  13  14,6    18
14  11,3    13,4    15,1    18,5
15  11,6    13,7    15,5    19
16  11,9    14  15,8    19,4
17  12,1    14,3    16,1    19,8
18  12,3    14,6    16,4    20,1
19  12,5    14,8    16,7    20,5
20  12,7    15  16,9    20,7
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input in the Note at the end this will plot them on a single panel.  Remove `facet=NULL` if you want separate panels.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF)
autoplot(z, facet = NULL) + geom_point()
```

(continued after graph)

[image: screenshot]

Using only base R this also works:

```
matplot(DF[[1]], DF[-1], type = "o")
legend("topleft", legend = names(DF)[-1], pch = as.character(1:4))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "s/e (IS 12,7)(IS 15,0)(IS 16,9)(IS 20,7)
1   0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1
2   1,2 1,4 1,5 1,9
3   2,8 3,3 3,7 4,6
4   4,4 5,2 5,8 7,1
5   5,7 6,7 7,6 9,3
6   6,8 8,1 9,1 11,1
7   7,7 9,1 10,3    12,6
8   8,5 10,1    11,3    13,9
9   9,2 10,8    12,2    15
10  9,7 11,5    12,9    15,9
11  10,2    12,1    13,6    16,7
12  10,6    12,6    14,1    17,4
13  11  13  14,6    18
14  11,3    13,4    15,1    18,5
15  11,6    13,7    15,5    19
16  11,9    14  15,8    19,4
17  12,1    14,3    16,1    19,8
18  12,3    14,6    16,4    20,1
19  12,5    14,8    16,7    20,5
20  12,7    15  16,9    20,7"

DF <- read.table(text = gsub("[()IS]", " ", Lines), header = TRUE, dec = ",",
 check.names = FALSE)
names(DF)[-1] <- paste("IS", names(DF)[-1])
```